# Query data on firebase realtime

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I have code in flutter where I am filtering data based on userId. But I also want that data to be sorted based on descsending order based on date. Like I want to show current day data first and then for previous date. In firestore its feasible while I am finding it hard to do with realtime. Below is code snippet where I have added query to filter by userId. Below I want to add sort data based on dates as well(I am saving timestamp)

```
_database.reference().child("node name here..").orderByChild("userId").
equalTo("my user id here...").once().then((snapshot )async{}
```

Answer (score 0):

FirebaseDatabase returns oldest data first ,In order to view latest data i would suggest you reverse the list or whilst saving your timestamp * by -1 to make document "oldest"

example

`int time = DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch;
var timestamp = time * -1;`

you can query your data as per this example

```
     return StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseDatabase.instance
            .reference()
            .child('node')
            .orderByChild('userid')
            .equalTo(userId)
            .onValue,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Event> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            if (snapshot.data.snapshot.value != null) {
              Map<dynamic, dynamic> map = snapshot.data.snapshot.value;
              List<dynamic> list = map.values.toList();


              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: list.length,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(13),
                        child: Container(
                          decoration:
                              BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blueGrey[100]),
                          child: ListTile(
                            title: Text(list[index]["title"]),
                            subtitle: Text(list[index]["text"]),
),
```

PS

**watch for you console to see if you get a link to create an [index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data)**

Comment: For some wiered reason realtime is returning me data in unordered manner. However in node I can see newest data at last of node. While I am fetching data for only particular userid out of multiple user list from firebase, it returns me in unordered manner. If I will reverse it, it wont solve my issue.

Comment: what should i do here.

Comment: Rtdb returns data oldest first ..try using negative timestamps

Comment: Okay I will add -1 in timestamp while adding data in node but where to add query in code for timestamp?

Comment: Not sure what you actually want but if it's to query using the timestamp you can always add `.orderByChild('userid')`

Comment: From my experience I have my query in. A stream builder

Comment: Can you please share how you're querying with both timestamp and child as "userid" as its returning me exception that I cannot have equalTo() along with 2 values(i.e userid and timestamp) for orderByChild()